# Laravel 5.4 : error database locked with sqlite

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5.4

I'm facing a pb with my sqlite database : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked (SQL: update "users" set "remember_token" = aeb4E7qmFKhOXl33TNLbCPFDwX2a2oha1NJEP7WIgMGAYKvrsqNNY36jrfT5, "updated_at" = 2017-04-12 22:19:08 where "id" = 1)

Some information: Laravel 5.4 Windows 10 Vagrant 1.9.1 (box laravel/homestead v. 2.1.0) VirtualBox

My homestead config file :

ip: "192.168.10.10" memory: 2048 cpus: 1 provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys: - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders: - map: E:/Work/Alsatia/extranet-laravel to: /home/vagrant/extranet-laravel type: smb

sites: - map: alsatia.local to: /home/vagrant/extranet-laravel/public

databases: - homestead

Absolutely no dev on laravel, it's a brant new projet, with authentication views generated by artisan make::auth. My .env contains : DB_CONNECTION=sqlite DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=../database/alsatia DB_USERNAME=homestead DB_PASSWORD=secret

The configuration seems to be ok because i managed to create a user with the register action. I can login (select in database OK), but the logout (update query) crashed with the error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked (SQL: update "users" set "remember_token" = aeb4E7qmFKhOXl33TNLbCPFDwX2a2oha1NJEP7WIgMGAYKvrsqNNY36jrfT5, "updated_at" = 2017-04-12 22:19:08 where "id" = 1)

What can i do to find more info about what happens here ?

Thank you for your help !